# When I LIKE my website none of my og properties are showing up in the news feed. Instead some Facebook default text shows up

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I got my code to validate with [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) but none of my properties are showing up on the new feed like I want them to.  Instead it seems to show a Facebook default text:

> Cosmetology & Spa Institute | Facebook www.facebook.com Facebook is a
>   social utility that connects people with friends and others who work,
>   study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with
>   friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos,
>   and learn more about the people they meet.

How can I get it to display my og properties?
All code on my site is below.

```html
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" id="facebook-jssdk"></script>
<meta property="og:title" content="Cosmetology Schools and Beauty Salons" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cosmetologyandspainstitute.com/facebook-tabs/CSI_Logo_2012-square.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.cosmetologyandspainstitute.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Cosmetology and Spa Institute" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1540268369" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The Cosmetology and Spa Institute has 2 of the best cosmetology and esthetician schools in Chicago. Our Illinois beauty schools, cosmetology and esthetics programs, provide results that truly matter." />
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div style="margin-left:25px" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/CosmetologySpaInstitute" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it – can’t find any problems, your description and image show up as in the meta elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `data-href` on your like button is pointed at a page on Facebook (http://www.facebook.com/CosmetologySpaInstitute) not the page the like button is on, so the opengraph tags never even get read. Instead Facebook scrapes what it can from the page on Facebook.

In effect, clicking like doesn't like your webpage, but your Facebook Page.